# MYSQL select unique id's where column value is not null in one or more records

Tags: mysql, sql

## Background

I have a table that contains customer purchase records, the table has a column named coupon_id, this column is null if a customer didn't use a coupon during a purchase and contained the coupon id if they did. The table can contain several purchases for a single customer, a customer may have used a coupon during one purchase and not during another.

```
+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| ID    | customer_id | coupon_id | other_data  | 
+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| 0     |  1          | 32        | ...         |
| 1     |  1          | null      | ...         |
| 2     |  1          | null      | ...         |
| 3     |  1          | null      | ...         |
| 4     |  2          | null      | ...         |
| 5     |  3          | 11        | ...         |
| 6     |  4          | null      | ...         |
| 7     |  4          | null      | ...         |
+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

## Problem

I want to get the customer_id for all customers who have never made a purchase using a coupon. The current query I am using is still returning customers that have made a purchase with a coupon.

```
SELECT customer_id from checkouts c 
WHERE code_id IS NULL
GROUP BY customer_id 
ORDER BY customer_id asc
```

## Question

How can I select a list of unique id's for costumers who have never purchased using a coupon?

Comment: what is `code_id`? did you mean `coupon_id`?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo.

Comment: then, `coupon_id IS NULL` is not working? I can't understand why use so complex query in below Answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `WHERE NOT EXISTS` and a subquery. Something like:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
        customer_id
    FROM checkouts c
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM checkouts
        WHERE
            checkouts.customer_id = c.customer_id
            AND coupon_id IS NOT NULL
    ) cc;
```

Not entirely sure if that's the correct MySQL syntax, but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Thanks, I had make a few changes to the syntax to get it working but the concept was correct.